# Is there an algebra group (or ring) in which computing the inverse element is hard without some trapdoor information?

Tags: rsa, elliptic-curves, finite-field, group-theory, ring-lwe

Specifically, I want an algebra group $G$ (or ring $R$) features:

1. Given elements $g,h\in G$ (or $R$ ), computing $g\cdot h \in G$ (or $R$ ) is easy.
2. Given an element $g \in G$  (or $R$ ), finding the inverse of $g$ is hard.
3. Given an element $g \in G$ (or $R$ ) and a trapdoor $\tau$, finding the inverse of $g$ is easy, s.t. $g\cdot g^{-1}=1_e$.

**Remark 1.** Due to the property of ring, $g\in R$ does not have correpsonding inverse. Even so, I still expect an approximate way to present the multiplication inverse of $g$ in Ring, or at least *partial elements* in Ring have multiplication "inverses"!

**Remark 2.**"easy" means the computation can be done in polynomial time, even if the group is very large, e.g., $|G|= 2^{256}$; On the contrary, "hard" means the computation cannot be done in polynomial time, if the group is very large.

I investigated traditional RSA, braid, and ECC groups, no such group can meet the above requirements.

The conjugacy problem in the braid group is that: Given $x,y$, where $y=a\cdot x \cdot a ^{-1}$, finding such $a$ is hard. Although, the problem does not meet my requirement, i.e., given $g$, finding $g^{-1}$ is hard, I tried to convert the conjugacy problem as below:

IF we have $x,a$ s.t. $y=a\cdot x \cdot a ^{-1}$, THEN $y\cdot y^{-1}=a\cdot x \cdot a ^{-1}\cdot y^{-1}=(a\cdot x)\cdot(a ^{-1}\cdot y^{-1})=1_e$; in which case, we let $g:=(a\cdot x), g^{-1}:=(a ^{-1}\cdot y^{-1})$, the new problem is that given such $g$, whether computing $g^{-1}$ is hard in braid group.

(But I think it is easy to compute, intuitively, due to we can multiply $g$ itself to find the inverse in $O(N)$ complexity where $N$ is $ord(G)$)

*Anyway*, if this kind of group or ring does exist, then we could have some interesting applications, e.g., efficient linear encryption and signature, and secure multiparty computation.

Taking MPC as the example, A has $x$, B has $y$, they want to compute $z=x\cdot y$. If the group or ring exists, then A computes $z_A = x\cdot g$, B computes $z_B = g^{-1} \cdot y$, finally $z=z_A \cdot z_B = x \cdot y$.

So, back to my question, does this kind of group (or ring) exist?

Comment: Remark: it follows from requirements 1 and 2 that the order $k$ of the group must be secret. Otherwise we could compute $g^{-1}$ as $g^{k-1}$ with less than $2\log_2k$ multiplications. So perhaps our trapdoor $τ$ can just be $k$. Also: perhaps the problem should be reformulated as: given bitstrings representing elements $g,h∈G$, computing a bitstring representing $g⋅h∈G$ is easy (polynomial with input size); stated if equality must be easy and public to test given bitstring representations; stated if the bitstrings must have bounded size.

Comment: @fgrieu Thank you for your comments. But as I known, in the unknown order group, such as RSA or quadratic residuce group, the extended euclidean algorithm can efficiently help one to compute the inverse of $g$. Thus, could you give me the example of the group you metioned?

Comment: @mingalex: I wrote, then removed, a broken attempt, based on the [Paillier cryptosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paillier_cryptosystem). It used $\mathbb Z_n^*$ or $\bigl[0,{\varphi(n)}\bigr)$ with $n$ an RSA modulus as the group, and $\mathbb Z_{n^2}^*$ for representations of an element using Paillier encryption. That allows computing the group operation on representations, while hiding the order, which is necessary. But, that does not make it hard to compute a representation of the inverse from a representation of an element, as asked if we reformulate in term of representations.

Comment: @fgrieu Okay, thanks a lot for your suggestions and efforts on my question!

Comment: The present question is not really a duplicate of [this one](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/58913/555), which additionally requires that "discrete logarithm and finding square root are believed to be hard".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trapdoor groups with infeasible inversion have been considered in several papers since the [Master's thesis of Hohenberger](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/87357/53226216-MIT.pdf). They were considered a hypothetical assumption for a long time, but two candidate constructions have appeared since:

- [one construction based on indistinguishability obfuscation](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/128), by Yamakawa et al. (CRYPTO 2014); and
- [one construction based on isogeny graphs over an RSA modulus](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/926), by Altug and Chen (ASIACRYPT 2019).

Neither of these constructions is a particularly clean instantiation of the primitive (there are issues with the growth of element reprensentations as well as how freely elements can compose, etc.), but they suffice in principle to instantiate the original protocols for which the concept was introduced in the first place. I recommend reading the introduction of the Altug-Chen paper for a good overview of the state of the art.

Despite the papers above, I think it is fair to argue that the problem remains to a large extent open.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clear answer to my question!